# Adding info to a database table. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have a database table, `UserInfo`. It is an extension of ASP.NET's built-in `aspnet_Users` table. `UserId` in the `UserInfo` table is a foreign key to `UserId` in the `aspnet_Users` table.

I have a account registration view model with the following fields: `First Name, Last Name, Phone Number, User Name, Email Address, Password, Confirm Password`

`User Name, Password, and Confirm Password` are already taken care of using ASP.NET's built-in Membership.

I would like to add `First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number` to the `UserInfo` table as well as reference the `UserId` from the `aspnet_Users` table when the account is created. I thought about if `MembershipCreateStatus` is a success, add the additional info to the `UserInfo` table with a reference to its `UserId`.

How do I add the info to the `UserInfo` table while making reference to its associated `UserId` in the `aspnet_Users` table? Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET membership allows you to get a user based on a username. So you can do a search with the username you've passed in, then get the Identity key as your reference.

Answer (score 1):

your guess is correct.

you can use asp.net membership as normal, provide the correct data to `Creatuser` method and then check for the returned value.

if `MembershipCreateStatus` is success, get the additional data from your page, create a new object, then save it as a new record to your additional table.

Comment: Thanks for the logic, Mohammed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I guess you could make your entity `UserInfo` inherit from entity `aspnet_Users` (select `UserInfo`, F4 to bring the property pane, and under "base type", select `aspnet_Users`

Comment: Not exactly. I just want to reference the `UserId` from the `aspnet_Users` table. `UserInfo` should not care about anything else in that table.

Perhaps I misunderstood what you said. Thanks for your answer.